# Android Studio Bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, libgdx

I want to use a Bitmap that I read about a little on Wikipedia. I want to make a cooldown animation that is grey at the beginning and becomes colored from the bottom to the top. I read a little about bitmaps from android studio, but things are a little bit confusing. How can I do what I want?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you asking how to do this in LibGDX or in Android in general?

Comment: I want the easier option, I don't care if I use LibGDX or not for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an animation list with a set of drawables in each state (from 0 to 100% for example) like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coldown_state10" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coldown_state20" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/coldown_state30" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

and in your activity something like this:

```
AnimationDrawable coldownAnimation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ImageView coldownImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coldown_image);
  coldownImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.coldown_state);
  coldownAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coldownImage.getBackground();
}
```

where coldown_state is the animation list.

Then when you need to trigger the animation simply do this:

```
coldownAnimation.start();
```

Comment: each item android:drawable="@drawable/coldown_state10" is a drawable, you cant edit the drawable colour from your code, you need to use several files.